# How do I alter the behavior of the form fields contained within the paragraph field?

Tags: 8, paragraphs

Using the [Paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) module in Drupal 8, I am attempting to alter the behavior of the form fields contained within the paragraph field. This is so I can add behavior like AJAX callbacks, hide show other fields using states etc.

I can access the paragraph parent field using this function:

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) { 
}
```

But how do I access the fields inside the paragraph?

I have tried `hook_field_widget_form_alter` but to no avail.

How do I do this?

Note: I am still quite new to Drupal development.

Comment: Try this in your alter, `kint($form);` and `kint($form_id);` and that should give you the id for the hook id alter and then it should also give you the array paths for what you want to alter.

Answer (score 31):

Since paragraphs^1.3 you can use [hook_field_widget_WIDGET_TYPE_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_WIDGET_TYPE_form_alter/8.2.x) (I linked the 8.2 version because there is a good comment about using the hook).

You can see the following example in `modules/contrib/paragraphs/tests/modules/paragraphs_test/paragraphs_test.module`

```
/**  
 * Implements hook_field_widget_WIDGET_TYPE_form_alter().  
 */  
function paragraphs_test_field_widget_entity_reference_paragraphs_form_alter(&$element, &$form_state, $context) {
  if ($element['#paragraph_type'] == 'altered_paragraph') {
    $element['subform']['field_text']['widget'][0]['#title'] = 'Altered title';
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that if you are using the "Paragraphs EXPERIMENTAL" widget instead of "Paragraphs Classic", then the widget type is just `paragraphs` instead of `entity_reference_paragraphs`.

Comment: Some useful things (because it's impossible to debug these hooks):

    `/* @var $paragraph \Drupal\paragraphs\Entity\Paragraph */
    $paragraph = $form_state->get('paragraph');

    $delta = $context['delta'];`

Comment: I am not sure how to alter some paragraph fields when the edit mode of that paragraph is set to "closed" in the form display. Because in that case, the 'subform' does not return any of the inline fields.

Comment: doesn't work for me but mymodule_field_widget_paragraphs_form_alter works, see below my answer if you are in the same case.

Comment: FYI `hook_field_widget_WIDGET_TYPE_form_alter` is deprecated
"[in drupal:9.2.0 and is removed from drupal:10.0.0. Use hook_field_widget_single_element_WIDGET_TYPE_form_alter instead.](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_WIDGET_TYPE_form_alter/9)"

Comment: @PratipGhosh I used a hook_field_widget_single_element_WIDGET_TYPE_form_alter() implementation and had same issue with paragraphs edit mode set to closed, however the ajax callback still triggers the hook. all you need to check is `if isset(element['subform']['field_whatever']))`

Answer (score 13):

If you are using [Paragraphs Browser](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs_browser) Field Widgets, then the `WIDGET_TYPE` ids for hook `hook_field_widget_WIDGET_TYPE_form_alter()` are different:

| Field Widget Label | Field Widget ID | Provider |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Paragraphs Classic | `entity_reference_paragraphs` | Paragraphs |
| Paragraphs EXPERIMENTAL | `paragraphs` | Paragraphs |
| Paragraphs Browser Classic | `entity_reference_paragraphs_browser` | Paragraphs Browser |
| Paragraphs Browser EXPERIMENTAL | `paragraphs_browser` | Paragraphs Browser |

Answer (score 3):

**Solved!** It works for me. hook_field_widget_WIDGET_TYPE_form_alter()  Soution 1 is working for me.

Dependee Field: "field_align"

Dependent Field: "field_tab_sticky" & "field_tab_content"

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_widget_WIDGET_TYPE_form_alter().
 */
function mymodule_field_widget_paragraphs_form_alter(&$element, &$form_state, $context) {
  if (!empty($element['subform']['field_dependee'])) {
    $parents_array = $element['subform']['#parents'];
    $parents = array_shift($parents_array) . '[' . implode('][', $parents_array) . ']';
    if (!empty($element['subform']['field_dependent'])) {
      $element['subform']['field_dependent']['#states'] = [
        'visible' => [
          ':input[name="' . $parents . '[field_dependee]"]' => [
            'value' => (string) 'some value',
          ],
        ],
      ];
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

**Solution 1**:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_widget_WIDGET_TYPE_form_alter().
 */
function HOOK_field_widget_paragraphs_form_alter(&$element, &$form_state, $context) {
  if (!empty($element['subform']['field_align'])) {
    $parents_array = $element['subform']['#parents'];
    $parents = array_shift($parents_array) . '[' . implode('][', $parents_array) . ']';
    if (!empty($element['subform']['field_tab_sticky'])) {
      $element['subform']['field_tab_sticky']['#states'] = [
        'visible' => [
          ':input[name="' . $parents . '[field_align]"]' => [
            'value' => (string) 'sticky',
          ],
        ],
      ];
    }
    if (!empty($element['subform']['field_tab_content'])) {
      $key = ':input[name="' . $parents . '[field_align]"]';
      $element['subform']['field_tab_content']['#states'] = [
        'visible' => [
          [$key => ['value' => (string) 'top']],
          'or',
          [$key => ['value' => (string) 'left']],
          'or',
          [$key => ['value' => (string) 'accordion']],
        ],
      ];
    }
  }
}
```

**Solution 2**: [Refer](https://agaric.coop/blog/conditional-fields-paragraphs-using-javascript-states-api-drupal-8)

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_widget_WIDGET_TYPE_form_alter().
 */
function HOOK_field_widget_paragraphs_form_alter(&$element, &$form_state, $context ) { 
  if($context['items']){

    $field_definition = $context['items']->getFieldDefinition();
    $paragraph_entity_reference_field_name = $field_definition->getName();

    if ($paragraph_entity_reference_field_name == 'field_content' && $element['#paragraph_type'] == 'tabs') { 

      $key = (isset($element['#type']) && $element['#type'] == 'container') ? $element['#field_parents'] : '';

      $widget_state = \Drupal\Core\Field\WidgetBase::getWidgetState($key, $paragraph_entity_reference_field_name, $form_state);

      $paragraph_instance = $widget_state['paragraphs'][$element['#delta']]['entity'];
      $paragraph_type = $paragraph_instance->bundle();

      if ($paragraph_type == 'tabs') {
        $dependee_field_name = 'field_align';
        $selector = sprintf('select[name="%s[%d][subform][%s]"]', $paragraph_entity_reference_field_name, $element['#delta'], $dependee_field_name);

        // Dependent fields.
        $element['subform']['field_tab_sticky']['#states'] = [
          'visible' => [
            $selector => ['value' => 'sticky'],
        ],
        ];

        // Dependent fields.
        $element['subform']['field_tab_content']['#states'] = [
          'visible' => [
            [$selector => ['value' => 'top']],
            'or',
            [$selector => ['value' => 'left']],
            'or',
            [$selector => ['value' => 'accordion']]
          ],
        ];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also, I agree with @baikho for hook references

Comment: Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Using `hook_form_alter` you could alter anything in the form, even stuff coming from widgets. It can easily get a bit messy and it tend to break easily when you mess around with widgets.

If you want to alter widgets what you can do it make your own widget. Widgets are plugins (PHP class) so you can make your own subclass the one you have and alter either by completely overwriting functions or by extending functions.

Widgets use annotation system, so you need to define name, id etc as comments above the class. Easiest way is simply to copy the original widget and alter give it a new name and id, rest should be like it needs to be.

Remember to clear cache to make Drupal find the new plugin.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Paragraphs Browser as field widget, things have one more twist for you.
The hook that fits is named `hook_field_widget_paragraphs_browser_form_alter()`
Took my quite some time to figure out...

Answer (score 1):

In my case ( Drupal 8/9 - multi paragraphs entity reference field)
hook mymodule_field_widget_entity_reference_paragraphs_form_alter doesn't work,
I used mymodule_field_widget_paragraphs_form_alter like this :

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_field_widget_WIDGET_TYPE_form_alter().
*/
function mymodule_field_widget_paragraphs_form_alter(&$element, &$form_state, $context) {
 if ( $element['#paragraph_type'] == 'content_selection') {
   //my specifid need 
   $element["subform"]["field_contents_related"]["widget"][0]["target_type"]["#options"]["taxonomy_term"] = t('Another text');
 }
}
```

Tips : to find quickly which field widget form alter is available in your form :

In core core/lib/Drupal/Core/Field/WidgetBase.php
Just before :

```
\Drupal::moduleHandler()->alter(['field_widget_form', 'field_widget_' . $this->getPluginId() . '_form'], $element, $form_state, $context);
```

(in my case line 353 in protected function formSingleElement )

```
\Drupal::messenger()->addMessage('field_widget_' . $this->getPluginId() . '_form');
```

You will see all the form field widget alter in my case :

field_widget_datetime_timestamp_form
field_widget_entity_browser_entity_reference_form
field_widget_multiple_options_select_form
field_widget_comment_default_form
field_widget_dynamic_entity_reference_default_form
field_widget_string_textfield_form
field_widget_paragraphs_form
field_widget_boolean_checkbox_form
field_widget_options_buttons_form
field_widget_text_textarea_form
field_widget_metatag_firehose_form
field_widget_entity_reference_autocomplete_form
field_widget_language_select_form
field_widget_path_form
field_widget_datetime_timestamp_no_default_form
field_widget_string_textarea_form

Comment: Thanks, this was useful.

Answer (score 1):

For Drupal 9.3 the `hook_field_widget_WIDGET_TYPE_form_alter()` is deprecated
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_WIDGET_TYPE_form_alter/9.3.x

We should use `hook_field_widget_single_element_WIDGET_TYPE_form_alter()`

Answer (score 1):

We shouldn't use `hook_field_widget_WIDGET_TYPE_form_alter` because this hook has been deprecated in drupal:9.2.0 and will be removed in 10.0.0.

Instead you should use [hook_field_widget_single_element_WIDGET_TYPE_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_single_element_WIDGET_TYPE_form_alter/10).

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal 10 the old method of altering the form (that most other answers on this page mention) has been removed.

The other answers on this page mention `hook_field_widget_WIDGET_TYPE_form_alter()` but that's tricky to figure out the machine name of your widget.  And if you want to experiment with another widget, your form alters will disappear.

So instead try `hook_field_widget_single_element_form_alter()`.  Here's the simplest example:

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_field_widget_single_element_form_alter().
 */
function MY_MODULE_field_widget_single_element_form_alter(&$element, FormStateInterface $form_state, $context) {
  if (isset($element['#paragraph_type']) && $element['#paragraph_type'] === 'my_paragraph_bundle') {
    $element['subform']['field_my_thing']['widget']['0']['#title'] = t('My new title');
  }

}
```

But you possibly want to alter forms for dozens of paragraphs and you don't want all that code in a single function.  And wouldn't it also be nice to have the Paragraph object (which is really hard to get in D10).  So try this technique of creating a pseudo hook (Search/replace "MY_MODULE" with the name of your module.  Then create as many implementations of the second function as you need them):

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_field_widget_single_element_form_alter().
 *
 * @link [https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/317870/3813] Description and discussion
 */
function MY_MODULE_field_widget_single_element_form_alter(&$element, FormStateInterface $form_state, $context) {
  if (!isset($element['#paragraph_type'])) {
    return;
  }
  $delta = $context['delta'];
  $paragraphBundle = $element['#paragraph_type'];

  /** @var \Drupal\field\Entity\FieldConfig $fieldDefinition */
  $fieldDefinition = $context['items']->getFieldDefinition();
  $contentFieldName = $fieldDefinition->getName();

  // @see \Drupal\paragraphs\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\ParagraphsWidget::formElement()
  $widgetState = \Drupal\Core\Field\WidgetBase::getWidgetState($element['#field_parents'], $contentFieldName, $form_state);

  // If this is an empty paragraph, do nothing.
  if (!isset($widgetState['paragraphs'][$delta])) {
    return;
  }

  // Don't act on Paragraph previews.
  if (!\Drupal\Core\Render\Element::children($element['subform'])) {
    return;
  }

  /** @var \Drupal\paragraphs\Entity\Paragraph $paragraph */
  $paragraph = $widgetState['paragraphs'][$delta]['entity'];

  $functionName = 'MY_MODULE_paragraph__' . $paragraphBundle . '__form_alter';
  if (function_exists($functionName)) {
    $functionName($element['subform'], $element, $form_state, $context, $delta, $paragraph);
  }
}

/**
 * Implements pseudo hook hook_paragraph__BUNDLE__form_alter().
 */
function MY_MODULE_paragraph__my_bundle__form_alter(array &$subform, array &$element, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, array $context, int $delta, \Drupal\paragraphs\Entity\Paragraph $paragraph):void {
  $subform['field_some_thing']['widget']['0']['#title'] = 'My new title';
}
```

Comment: This is the way.

Answer (score 0):

There's [a patch for this in the Paragraphs issue queue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2868155).

It adds new hooks:

```
hook_form_paragraphs_subform_alter()
hook_form_paragraphs_subform_TYPE_alter()
hook_form_paragraphs_subform_WIDGET_alter()
hook_form_paragraphs_subform_WIDGET_TYPE_alter()
```

Comment: [Per this comment](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs/issues/2868155#comment-12767803), those hooks were not added in favor of core's `hook_field_widget_WIDGET_TYPE_form_alter()`.